# Incorrect scale in WebView

Tags: android, primefaces, webview, webkit, primefaces-mobile

I have a website built on top of PrimeFaces. My problem is that the content and the images on the WebView appear larger than on Chrome. What should I do to make rendering on WebView identical to that of Chrome?

Scaling does not seem to help because the website has a responsive design. I have also tried `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent` with no success.

**Update 1**:
The followings have no effect. I have excluded them from the code below to keep it minimal.

- `WebViewClient`
- `ChromeViewClient`
- `setLoadWithOverviewMode(true)`
- `setUseWideViewPort(true)`

**Update 2**:
`setInitialScale()` has no effect.

**MyActivity.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.xhtml");
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            a:layout_width="fill_parent"
            a:layout_height="fill_parent"
            a:background="#ffffff"
            a:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView a:id="@+id/web_engine"
         a:layout_width="fill_parent"
         a:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

[image: WebView]
[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

More specifically here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html#TEXT_AUTOSIZING

Full code here:

```
mWebView = (WebView) mLayoutMain.findViewById(R.id.webview_main);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.xhtml");
```

Comment: It has no effect (see Update 2). Did you actually try it?

Comment: They are identical on my device (KitKat 4.4.4, Moto X). What are you using to test with?

Comment: KitKat 4.4.4, Nexus 4. Are they identical to the first or to the second picture? Were they identical with my original code or after adding some particular configuration? Can you attach screenshots?

Comment: I'm seeing clearly different values being calculated when I inspect the relative WebViews in Chrome's Dev Tools. Specifically in the 'main' role div tag

Comment: Ah ha! figured it out. At least on my device. Editing answer to reflect my changes.

Comment: This didn't help unfortunately. Can you send a snapshot (actually 2 if possible)?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, where the problem was that the system font size (Settings -> Display -> Font size) affected the font size in the WebView, but not in the browser.

As I'm using cordova, I solved the issue with a [cordova plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003829/phonegap-ignore-font-size-display-setting-on-android)

Looking at the plugin code it does the following in Android to reset the font size:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setTextZoom(100);
```

Or (pre ICS):

```
mWebView.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I will recommend you to test your app on different mobile browser. If same problem then see below :

The difference between the browser and your app is probably because you are making mistake while using the setUseWideViewPort WebSetting to true.

Check below links :

1. [why does my font-size look so much larger in the android webview object than when viewed in the android browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891465/why-does-my-font-size-look-so-much-larger-in-the-android-webview-object-than-whe)
2. [Android WebView text zoom for different screens and os version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974633/android-webview-text-zoom-for-different-screens-and-os-version)
3. [WebView text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573666/webview-text-size)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Rendering on the mobile browser (Chrome) is perfect. So I don't need to check a different browser.

Can you include a tested code that would correct the mistake I might be making?

I had seen these questions before I asked mine. Changing the text size has an effect. But, the images remain bigger than they should.

Comment: Try this for images webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

Comment: Reference link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099344/can-androids-webview-automatically-resize-huge-images

Comment: Thanks. The images are still rendered bigger than they should. In addition, when the web page contains an AdSense ad, the ad box is bigger in the WebView version. I don't think this problem is solvable by fixing the text, image, etc. Instead, it should be related to a parameter that controls the overall size.

Answer (score 1):

I tried http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/mobile/index.xhtml in both mobile chrome and within application, and they both looks similar

**Within application**

[image]

**In Chrome**

[image]

I don't see any issues. Is it possible that you are getting difference in some specific android version? I verified it on 4.4.4

Comment: Strange. I'm running on 4.4.4 as well with Nexus 4. Have you executed the same exact code that I included in my question or you made some modifications?

Comment: Yup. The settings are same.. Only difference is that I am using match parent for layout width and height and my web view is child of a linear layout.

Comment: I tried linear layout and match parent. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

For font size to match chrome or website without any resizing just do `webSettings.setMinimumFontSize(1);`

Kind Regards
Ramin