# Angular Material Icon not centered in Android App with Cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova, webview, angular-material

I am writing an [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) App, and in my code I have an [angular material icon](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview):

```
<mat-icon>mood</mat-icon>
```

Which looks perfect in browser when I was developing:

**Properly displayed icon in browser:**

[image]

But when I compile the project and deploy to my Android phone, I found the icons are not centered. Not among other texts, but within the icon itself:

**Mat icon that offsets:**

[image]

I am really confused on why is this happening and what is the direction to look for a solution.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after 7 months:
I had text zoom enabled in my phone, and this solved it:

[Phonegap - Ignore font-size display setting on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003829/phonegap-ignore-font-size-display-setting-on-android)